# How to transfer data from one file to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am having two files such as,

**employee-rates-controller.ts:**

```
private load() {

return this.entityService
      .load(this.$scope.projectRevisionUid)
      .then(resp => {
        localStorage.removeItem('employeerates');
        this.$scope.employeeRates = resp.employeeRates;
        return this.refreshCostRate(...resp.employeeRates)
          .then(() =>
            localStorage.setItem(
              'employeerates',
              JSON.stringify(this.$scope.employeeRates)
            )
          )
      .then(() => this.refreshBillRate(...resp.employeeRates))
      .then(() => resp.employeeRates.forEach(erm => this.calculate(erm)))
      .then(() => DatepickerUtil.reinitializeDatepickers(this.$scope));
      })

}
```

And in another file,

**getEmployeeRates.ts:**

```
  const employeerates = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem('employeerates')
  );

  if (employeerates && employeerates.length != null) {
    employeerates.forEach((element: any) => {
      if (
        this.employee.getUid() === element.user.personUid &&
        element.internalRate
      ) {
        this.cost_rate_uom = element.internalRate * this.uom_factor;
        this.cost_rate_per_hour =
          this.cost_rate_uom / this.uom_factor;
        this.cost_rate.setValue(this.ap4_cost_rate_per_hour);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here you can see,

In first ts file,

```
localStorage.setItem('employeerates',JSON.stringify(this.$scope.employeeRates))
```

And in second ts file receiving the data,

```
const employeerates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeerates'));
```

I couldn't not find any problem if i add very few employees but when i keep on adding employee which means storing them into `localstorage`, i am getting the error at certain point of time when the data size was huge and it blocks the entire process.

The error was,

> QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting
>   the value of 'employeerates' exceeded the quota.

So i would like to get some good solution in transferring any large data from one file to another without using the localstorage..

As the application is made in **Angularjs and Typescript** combination, i couldn't find out right solution as i am new to this scenario.

**Edit:**

Instead of first TS file, i am also able to get the value in this file.

employeeratemodel.ts:

```
export class EmployeeRateModel {
public uid: string;
.
.
.
public internalRate: number; // Getting the value here
}
```

How to fetch this value inside the second ts `getEmployeeRates.ts:` file..

My try:

```
import { EmployeeRateModel } from '../component/employee-rates/model/employee-rate.model';

constructor() {
    const data = new EmployeeRateModel();
    console.log(data) // {}  // Gives empty object.. I need to fetch the internalRate from it..
  }
```

Here if i get the data then it will be ease for me to get the `internalRate` which is needed for calculation, but as everything returns empty, this also fails for me..

Kindly help me to fix it in appropriate way, stucked for long..

Comment: why don't you use server-side storage to store employee data?

Comment: can't you use a service?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I tried through service but i am getting the data as undefined.. If possible can you provide me one good solution please..

Comment: @skdroid, No i cannot go with server side, it is the requirement i need to handle everything in front end.. Only thing is i need to share the data from one file to another as localstorage is not working for large data seeking help for other alternative..

Comment: how did you implement a service, if you got the data as undefined that means you may have some problems with promises, you should return promises from your service

Comment: Service will be the one and only solution to this. If you don't want to use it, don't use angular at all.

Comment: @madalinivascu, I am having the entire data in employeeratemodel.ts file which gives needed data so i tried to import it into ```getEmployeeRates.ts``` like ```import { EmployeeRateModel } from '../component/employee-rates/model/employee-rate.model';``` and when i instantiate like ```console.log('EmployeeRateModel ', new EmployeeRateModel());``` it gives empty ```EmployeeRateModel {}``` so i am trying to take internalRate from it like ```new EmployeeRateModel().internalRate``` which is undefined.. For your ref it is not service but i am getting needed data from this file..

Comment: @sandrooco, At no point of time i said that i am not interested in using service.. If the service way then i just seeking help, i am facing few problems in it.. As this scenario is new for me i am quite confused in transferring the data through service..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur That's totally fine, I'd open up a new question about the service with all service code you had.
What Angular version are you using?

Comment: @sandrooco, Its version ```"@types/angular": "~1.6.42",``` i am using angularjs and typescript..

Comment: You can try like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075686/get-value-from-another-component-angular-7

Comment: @sandrooco. As i made a lengthy comment above regarding the file ```EmployeeRateModel``` that has the data i am in the need and i just need to import and receive the internal rate from it..

Comment: @sandrooco, Typescript version ```"typescript": "~2.7.1",``` ..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur why don't you use `rxJs` subject for the same?

Comment: @YashRami, My TS version doesn't support..

Comment: @sandrooco, Please help me with my edited question ```EmployeeRateModel``` instead of my first ts file, we can take this file where i am getting data i just need to fetch this data in my second ts file..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur have you tried the blob option I mentioned below?

Answer (score 0):

use [IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb), it is a large-scale, NoSQL storage system. It lets you store just about anything in the user's browser and it has a [huge limit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) based on the client computer approx 20% of total storage.

NPM Package [Angular IndexedDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indexeddb-angular)

Comment: I guess service would be best solution for this

Comment: yes, but what if user close browser and open it again then all the data will vanish, to persist data storage is needed. @v8-E

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's Local Storage default size is 10 Mb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage), so clearing your chrome's local storage could help you, if your data is larger than the limits, you may need to find alternatives like storing on blob storage and accessing the contents from blob itself.

For the reference, you can handle the error if you want using the code below.

```js
try {
     var counter = 1;
     var stringData = "AddLocalStorageTillItIsFull";
     for (var i = 0; i <= counter; counter + 1) {
         stringData += stringData;
         localStorage.setItem("localStorageData", stringData);
         console.log(stringData);
         console.log(counter);
     }

 }
 catch (e) {
     // When local storage is full, it goes hits this carch block
     console.log("Local Storage is full, Please clear local storage data to add more");
 }
```

Comment: That's not for the user, this is for the developer to handle the storage. Local storage has the limitation and it is not recommended to use local storage for larger data. Using the blob storage would be recommended to access files across different controllers.