# Angular 2 three component data transfer

Tags: angular, input, components, output

I have 3 Angular Components.
the first one is **app.component**
the second **test1.component** and
third **test2.component**

**app.component.html**

```
<app-test1 [(value)]="name" ></app-test1>
<button (click)="click()">Save</button>
```

**test1.component.html**

```
<app-test2 [(value)]="value"></app-test2>
```

**test2.component.html**

```
<input type="test" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

I want to transfer the test 2.component input change directly to the app.component without using the "Output". (this.name)

if i'm using the "output"i will have to use an extra (entitychange) and i don't want that.

```
✔ <input type="test" [(ngModel)]="value">
❌ <input type="test" [(ngModel)]="value" (entityChange)="value = $event">
```

Sample for you to try: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ge7dje)
I want to do without output.

Comment: you can use `RxJs` subject for the same here is the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075999/5746236

Answer (score 2):

Create a service with rxjs Subject prop and inject it in app and test2

// property in service

```
 inputUpdate = new Subject()
```

In test2
// inject service in constructor

```
<input type="test" (change)="someService.inputUpdate.next($event)>
```

In app inject same service in constructor
And subscribe to updates

```
this.someService.inputUpdate.subscribe( (value) => { //do smth  })
```